# How to set a memory limitation per request on Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created an Azure Function App(.Net 6 Isolated) utilizing the Consumption plan, which is responsible for converting various documents from one format to another, such as converting PDFs to PNGs. However, the processing time for certain documents may be longer due to factors such as the size of the document. I am aware that the Consumption plan has a memory limitation of 1.5 GB per function app. There are two function endpoints on the app, and I would like to set a hard limit on the memory usage per request to ensure that it does not exceed 512 MB. Is this possible?

Comment: There is no such per Function memory capping ability AFAIK. When you are doing a very large document processing and you need hundreds of MB of RAM, then you could make use of the class `MemoryFailPoint` in System.Runtime namespace. check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks! But the MemoryFailPoint class does not guarantee that the block of code will execute within a specific amount of memory. It only ensures that a certain amount of memory is available before executing the code. The actual memory usage of the code may be higher than the specified amount.

Answer (score 0):

> But the MemoryFailPoint class does not guarantee that the block of code will execute within a specific amount of memory. It only ensures that a certain amount of memory is available before executing the code

- This functionality of setting the memory consumption size is available for the Azure Functions before the Year of 2016.
- There have been few changes in the Serverless design especially Azure Functions on utilizing of the dependent resources.
- Microsoft has disabled the memory setting in Consumption Plan based on the experience feedback from many of Azure Users and brought up the change that the Consumption Hosting Plan will decides the resource utilization including memory/CPU based on your usage of Functions.

*Refer to this [MS Article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/making-azure-functions-more-serverless/?ref=msdn) for more information on memory settings to each of our function apps.*